# Pervasive PSQL - select last two orders by customer

Tags: pervasive

**How can I select last two orders by every customer ?**

*query:*

```
select custcode, invcode, invvalue, invdata from INV INV1
where invdata = (select top 2 invdata from INV INV2 where INV1.id = INV2.id order by INV2.data DESC)
```

is not working, there is no possibility to order in subquery.

I'm using `PSQL v11 x64 SP3`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `IN` rather than the `=` in your query.  For example, this works for me:

> select * from class where start_date in (select top 2 start_date from
>   class where start_date > '1995-06-05')

Try:

> select custcode, invcode, invvalue, invdata from INV INV1 where
>   invdata in (select top 2 invdata from INV INV2 where INV1.id = INV2.id
>   order by INV2.data DESC)

If that doesn't work, edit your post to include the actual error or behavior you are seeing.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/ODBC/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=syntaxref.03.71.html#2342549&single=true), only Table subqueries support ORDER BY.